# How to get a value outside of a firebase callback?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I guess this is not a Firebase question as much as it is a callback syntax question:

I want the function **changeName** to go to Firebase database and replace the value of "t" with a value that is a child of "t" in the database.

```
function changeName (t) {
    return (
        t.replace(t, firebase.database().ref(`langs/${t}`).once('value', snap => snap.val().name))
    )
}
```

But I get `[object Promise]`.

The code does work when I put an `alert()` method inside the snap arrow function, so I know the access to the value is fine. I just couldn't figure out how to get the value as a string of text for the `replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    function changeName (t) {
        return (
                firebase.database().ref(`langs/${t}`).once('value', snap => {
                t.replace(t, snap.val().name);
            })
            
        )
    }
```